# Disabling only a single ggplot2/tidyverse lifecycle/deprecated warning? (Not all lifecycle warnings)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have some R code that uses ggplot2 and may continue to use aes_string() for a while despite that function being deprecated. The code also uses source() to bring in some other functions that use aes_string(), which I do not have access to edit without making/maintaining a separate copy of the included code.

I know I can disable ***all*** tidyverse lifecycle messages with: `rlang::local_options(lifecycle_verbosity = "quiet")` but I don't necessarily want to disable all of them - I may still update other parts of the code to match changes in ggplot2, even while continuing to use aes_string().

Is there any way to disable the deprecated message *only* for aes_string() and not for everything else?

Comment: The reason I care about disabling this message is because the code will run on a high-performance computing cluster where output to the standard error during a job produces some mildly-obnoxious behavior. I will just disable all the lifecycle messages if I have to, but if possible I'd rather just disable the message for aes_string() and still see other deprecated messages I might want to know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the `aes_string()` call in `suppressWarnings()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes_string("cty", "hwy")) +
  geom_point()
# Warning message:
# `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0.
# ℹ Please use tidy evaluation ideoms with `aes()` 

ggplot(mpg, suppressWarnings(aes_string("cty", "hwy"))) +
  geom_point()
# [no warning printed]
```

Or if you want to be sure to suppress only that specific warning, you could define a custom handler function like:

```r
suppressDeprecationWarning <- function(...) {
  withCallingHandlers(
    ..., 
    warning = \(w) if ("`aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0." %in% w$message) {
      rlang::cnd_muffle(w)
    }
  )
}

ggplot(mpg, suppressDeprecationWarning(aes_string("cty", "hwy"))) +
  geom_point()
# [no warning printed]
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work, but I can only do it in places where the use of aes_string() is in my own code. If I'm using code shared by members of the lab I'd have to suppressWarnings() the call to their function that uses aes_string(), and that would possibly hide other important warnings.

Comment: See my edited answer — you should be able to use the custom handler function for calling your lab members’ function.

Comment: That worked perfectly, both for direct use and use on other peoples' functions. Thank you for saving the sanity of a bunch of postdocs and grad students!!